# Display errors inside the navigator in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I get a syntax error in a source code in Eclipse, I get the usual red cross mark.

Unfortunately some time ago I was used to get the red crosses in the Navigator, very clear to spot the files that contain errors; then I don't know why, now I don't get the errors displayed there, but only inside the source code and in the "Problems view". Not that I'm against the Problems view, but it does not collect the errors that appear in one single file, and hence is much more annoying and less clear than a simple red cross near the file name.

Does some one know how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know the Navigator Window never shows errors - at least it  doesn't in mine. Use either project Explorer or Package Explorer which do.  Window > Show View >...

Comment: That's it thank you!!! Indeed, I was using the Navigator instead of the Package Explorer!